# Finding out the total runs in an over where table has only Balls and Runs columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

Table - Cricket:

```
Balls Runs
1     6
2     0
3     1
4     3
5     2
6     1
1     0
2     2
3     6
4     1
5     4
6     1
.
.continue n no of times..
```

Now the output should be like:

```
Over Runs
1    13  ( sum of first 6 balls which makes a over)
2    14
```

Continue this as per the above example..

Can anyone help me in getting this either in Oracle or SQL Server?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? What does your table structure look like? You need to give us a start at least.

Comment: Will there always be six records per cycle or can this vary?

Comment: Based on your data, a simple `group by` solves the problem.  What have you tried?

Comment: Is this for Oracle or SQL Server? You say either, but they are 2 completely different RDBMS. Also, I cannot see any kind of column that allows you to group your rows into the groups you want. A table in a DBMS has no "natural order", so how do you define that the first row in your sample data is in Over, 1, 2, or 17?

Comment: Since Balls are repeating, it there a proper sequence like identity or TS?

Comment: For identify column I have tried with the Rownum but as group by function is not working as there are no such columns to grp..so had a real tough time to solve it...

Comment: You could create an over to ball mapping table (either physical/temp or parameterised that has the start/end ball numbers and then join the cricket table to said overball table to get the associated over `LEFT JOIN OVER_BALL ON CRICKET.BALL BETWEEN START_BALL AND END_BALL`

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible with the structure in your question (i.e. only `Balls` and `Runs` columns). Tables in SQL databases have no natural order, so there is no guarantee that you will get the data in any specific order. You need to have a column that allows you to group your rows as you want. For example, say you have an `Over` column:

```
Over Balls Runs
1    1     6
1    2     0
1    3     1
1    4     3
1    5     2
1    6     1
2    1     0
2    2     2
2    3     6
2    4     1
2    5     4
2    6     1
```

You can use a simple grouping query like:

```
SELEC "Over", SUM(Runs) AS Runs
FROM Cricket
GROUP BY "Over"
```

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted, shame on them for not commenting.

Comment: @Larnu Also not sure why, but there is zero shame, in fact it's mostly discouraged to comment when downvoting

Comment: The rule/advice of not commenting when downvoting is completely ridiculous. There is a big debate about it on meta, but hopefully one day a new generation will simply start ignoring it and comment constructively so we can all benefit. A downvote alone adds no value or useful meaning beyond the disagreement with the answer. I've had others commenting constructively on my answers sometimes with or without a downvote, and I've always appreciated that. I always leave a comment on other answers.

Comment: @DavidG why would it be discourage to comment when downvoting? If someone downvotes an answer then how will the author know what is wrong with it, or how to improve? This is a website for sharing answers and knowledge... Upvotes left uncommented are fine, but certainly not the other way round. Users won't learn otherwise. I certainly always make the effort to comment on how the answer can be improved, or isn't relevant when i downvote (unless it's already been commented about). In fact I will often comment first and go back to check if the OP has made an effort before downvoting.

Comment: @Larnu Because too many people take downvotes personally resulting in revenge voting. 99% of downvotes are for patently obvious reasons anyway so don't need comments. As for why this answer was voted, no idea, maybe because the question was so lazy that someone thought it shouldn't be answered?

Comment: @DavidG that's goes further to say shame on the user who is revenge voting then. People like that don't add to the community; they just make it toxic (and why SO can have a bad reputation). Anyway, we're off topic here.

Comment: @Larnu But you called shame on the initial downvoter, I vehemently disagree with that statement.

Answer (score 1):

Like I said in the comment, you can't do this as is. As a demostration:

```
USE Sandbox;
GO

CREATE TABLE Cricket (Ball int, Runs int);
INSERT INTO Cricket
VALUES (1,6),
       (2,0),
       (3,1),
       (4,3),
       (5,2),
       (6,1),
       (1,0),
       (2,2),
       (3,6),
       (4,1),
       (5,4),
       (6,1);
GO
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT Ball, Runs,
           (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY NEWID())-1) / 6 AS [Over]--NEWID as your table has nothing to identify an order
    FROM Cricket)
SELECT [Over],
       SUM(Runs) AS Runs --This won't be correct
FROM CTE
GROUP BY [Over];

GO
DROP TABLE Cricket;
GO
```

YOu need someone to know what order the balls were in, so, I've added an `IDENTITY` column:

```
--Fix the problem, add an identity

CREATE TABLE Cricket (ID int IDENTITY(1,1), Ball int, Runs int);
INSERT INTO Cricket (Ball, Runs)
VALUES (1,6),
       (2,0),
       (3,1),
       (4,3),
       (5,2),
       (6,1),
       (1,0),
       (2,2),
       (3,6),
       (4,1),
       (5,4),
       (6,1);
GO
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT Ball, Runs,
           (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID)-1) / 6 AS [Over]
    FROM Cricket)
SELECT [Over],
       SUM(Runs) AS Runs --Hazaar!
FROM CTE
GROUP BY [Over];

GO
DROP TABLE Cricket;
```

Now you get the correct results. With the data you have right now, though, the answer is **impossible**.

Answer (score 0):

You really need a 3rd column to either track overs or to contain a unique sequential id for the rows.

It is possible to do it without in Oracle but you are relying on the database always reading the rows in the same order (and while this is generally true it is not always true - especially on parallel systems or if the table has row movement enabled). As soon as the rows are read in a different order then your results will be messed up - so add a third column rather than relying on things that may change.

You can use the `ROW_NUMBER()` analytic function and the `ROWNUM` pseudo-column to simulate a sequnce value:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8865ee/1)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name ( Balls, Runs ) AS
  SELECT 1,     6 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2,     0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 3,     1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 4,     3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 5,     2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 6,     1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 1,     0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2,     2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 3,     6 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 4,     1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 5,     4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 6,     1 FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT overs,
       SUM( runs ) AS runs
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY Balls ORDER BY ROWNUM ) AS overs
  FROM   table_name t
)
GROUP BY overs
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8865ee/1/0)**:

```
| OVERS | RUNS |
|-------|------|
|     1 |   13 |
|     2 |   14 |
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select overs,sum(runs) from 
(select runs,case when rownum between 1 and 6 then 'over_1'
                  when rownum between 7 and 12 then 'over_2' end as overs from cricket_info) group by overs order by overs;
```

Out_put:

```
over_1  21
over_2  16
 -  5
```

Answer (score 0):

The below query will resolve this:

```
select *,row_number() over() as overno from (
select overrun from(
select *,sum(runs)  over(partition by ball in(1,2,3,4,5,6) rows between 0 preceding and 5 following ) as overrun from cricket order by ball )a where ball =1)b
```

The table contains 2 columns ball and run. So we need to partition the table for every 6 rows which constitutes an over this is done by "partition by ball in(1,2,3,4,5,6)" .After Partition we need to sum all the runs corresponding to the balls 1,2,3,4,5,6 which is done by "sum(runs) over (rows between 0 preceding and 5 following)". Then we need to select only the run per over and then add a row number to it.

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Answer (score -1):

SELECT overs, SUM( runs ) AS runs
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY mod ORDER BY balls) AS overs
  FROM   (SELECT t.*,mod(balls,6) mod from CRICKET t) t

)group by overs;

Answer (score -1):

```
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT Balls, Runs,
           (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Balls)-1) / 6 AS [Over]
    FROM Cricket)
SELECT [Over]+1,
       SUM(Runs) AS TotalRuns  
FROM CTE
GROUP BY [Over];
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.